# How can I check whether an extension(BHO) is installed in IE 6/7/8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

How can I check whether an extension(BHO) is installed in IE 6/7/8, with javascript code in a webpage?

Comment: Hi Dr. Molle, its a IE toolbar, with has a search box.

Comment: Hi Dr. Molle, any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include an [ActiveX contro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)l in your extension.

1. This should be a separate COM object from your BHO.
2. Make sure to [SiteLock](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23438) the control to your domain.

Then, on your website, you can just try to create that control:

```
var foo;
try {
    foo = new ActiveXObject("your.control");
} catch (e) {
    foo = null;
}

if (foo == null) {
    // Your package not installed.
}
```

Comment: Hi, I dont know program activex control, :( is there any other way?

Comment: Hi, is the possble to inject dom in the extension? like set document.somevar = 1 when the extension is running? thanks.

Comment: Well, ActiveX is just a COM object (IUnknown) + some registration.  The link I included explains everything.  In this case it's very simple since you don't need any UI.  Most people want more communication between the page and their extension, so you'll probably end up doing an ActiveX control eventually.  But if you really just want to know if your extension is installed, you could modify the user-agent string.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx#UARegistry